# Google Apps Script error: You do not have permission to call createEvent (line 57, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to create an event in Google Calendar from Google Apps Script. When I run the following line

```
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 
Landing',
new Date('February 22, 2017 13:00:00 UTC'),
new Date('February 22, 2017 14:00:00 UTC'));
```

I'm getting 'You do not have permission to call createEvent'.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have given the scopes as 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' any way I'm getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly on Apps Script as I tested it:

```
function creatCalEvent(){
     var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',new Date('February 29, 2018 13:00:00 UTC'),  new Date('February 30, 2018 14:00:00 UTC')); 
}
```

I don't know where you even put the 'googleapis.com/auth/calendar' scope as I didn't need to do anything like that. Just make sure you're logged into your account.

Screenshot:

[image]